# Django: How do I customize the default add-page for the AbstractUser model

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a model `CustomUser` which extends Django's built-in `AbstractUser` class.

Among other fields, `AbstractUser` contains `username`, `first_name`, and `last_name`.

In the `CustomUser` model, `username` is automatically generated from the `first_name` and `last_name` fields.

For this reason, I have overridden the `first_name` and `last_name` fields to make them mandatory.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.username = self.generate_username()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

By default, the admin **add-user page** (`/admin/myapp/customuser/add/`) looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyvmL.png).

How can I make the form in the admin add-page show the `first_name` and `last_name` fields instead of the `username` field?